# Converting C# Console App to MVC 5 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, console-application

I was wondering if there is any way to take a console application and switch it to a ASP.NET MVC5 Web Application.

I have a Regression ML Console Application that I want to create a web form with

Answer (score 0):

You can make a DLL of your console application, and then use the classes and methods from the DLL by adding reference of the DLL to the MVC project.

To make DLL of the console application, `Right click on your Console Application -> Properties -> Change the Output type to Class Library` and build the project.

To add reference of the DLL, R`ight click on your MVC project References->Add References->Browse`, and select the DLL you just made.

Now, go to the controller where you want to use the DLL's code, write `using` and the DLL name with its namespace. Now, you can access the classes, and methods of the DLL in this controller.

Comment: I am really new to this so is there a step-by-step reference website or tutorial I can view so I know Im doing the right thing?